# Can this matrix equation be solved for X?

Tags: matrices

$(A^TA+aI)^{-1}A^T = A^TX$

where A and X are real-matrices and a is a positive non-zero real number. A is non-zero and you may assume that A is such that there is a unique X that satisfies the above equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the inverse of the inverse so to speak:

$$A^T=(A^TA+aI)A^TX$$
$$A^T=A^T(AA^T+aI)X$$

and now if $X=(AA^T+aI)^{-1}$ it is solved.

Comment: $(A^TA+aI)A^T=(A^TAA^T+aIA^T)=A^T(AA^T+aI)$

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put -1 in the power

Comment: I have changed the question now

Comment: Thanx, this is perfect

Comment: Glad I could help!